# Discord Auto Killed

Tags: steam, playonlinux

I am using ubuntu 19.10
When I am playing Dota 2 using steam and using discord for voice chat, my discord automatically quits after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes sound applications using PulseAudio may quit unexpectedly due to the sound latency factor PulseAudio has configured. To try to solve this closure, you can run the program in the terminal by modifying this parameter:

```
PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 discord
```

You can also try the value 90 instead of 60. In my case it caused Discord to close much less. If you notice the difference, you can modify the program launcher with the following command so that it always runs with that option:

```
env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 /usr/bin/discord
```

Another possible solution would be to try using the Discord snap package. With the following commands you can install it, but previously you will have to uninstall the existing one:

```
sudo apt-get remove discord

sudo apt-get install snapd

sudo snap install discord
```

Try some of these solutions and tell us.

Comment: Either way, it appears to be a widespread bug that developers are currently fixing: https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360058611531-Discord-shutting-down-randomly-ingame-Linux-